# catkin_make with common_msgs as a dependency

Tags: catkin-make, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use some of the common_msgs in a ROS node I'm working on so used catkin_create_pkg with common_msgs as a dependency (Similar to what is done in the simple publisher subscriber with std_msgs)

I get the following error when running catkin_make

```
-- Could not find the required component 'common_msgs'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "common_msgs" with
  any of the following names:

    common_msgsConfig.cmake
    common_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "common_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "common_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "common_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ZenithObstacleDetector/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

I made sure common_msgs is installed and used roscd to enter it. It only contains a package.xml file.

Here's the package I'm working on https://github.com/iscumd/ZenithObstacleDetector

I've commented out the find common_msgs so it builds

Here's the workspace https://github.com/iscumd/Zenith2017/tree/master/catkin_ws

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249556/catkin_make-with-common_msgs-as-a-dependency/) by [copyat300](https://answers.ros.org/users/28747/copyat300/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`common_msgs` is the [metapackage](http://wiki.ros.org/Metapackages), not a package that contains any files itself (other than a package manifest).

You should depend on the package(s) that actually contain the message/service/action specs that you'd like to use (ie, any of: `actionlib_msgs`, `diagnostic_msgs`, `geometry_msgs`, `nav_msgs`, `sensor_msgs`, `shape_msgs`, `stereo_msgs`, `trajectory_msgs` or `visualization_msgs`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [copyat300](https://answers.ros.org/users/28747/copyat300/) on 2016-12-07**:
Thank you, I realized I could include the sensor_msgs on it's own but didn't realize this was the "correct" way to do it.